# Swift 4 adding annotations error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping

Tags: swift, mapkit

I'm simply trying to add an annotation to my map view but I keep running into this error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping" and I can't seem to solve it or find a solution that works in my case. Could someone please tell me where I have gone wrong. Thanks in advance. I have already tried to change the `var mapView: MKMapView!` to `var mapView: MKMapView?` with no success

```
class customPin: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
var title: String?
var subtitle: String?

init(pinTitle:String, pinSubTitle:String, location:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.title = pinTitle
    self.subtitle = pinSubTitle
    self.coordinate = location
}
}

var mapView: MKMapView!
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 32.2325, longitude:76.3242)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.005, longitudeDelta: 0.005))
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    let pin = customPin(pinTitle: "Honory Dalailama Temple", pinSubTitle: "Dharamshala, Himachal Pradesh, India", location: location)
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(pin)
    self.mapView.delegate = self
}


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "customannotation")
    annotationView.image = UIImage(named:"pin")
    annotationView.canShowCallout = true
    return annotationView
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    print("annotation title == \(String(describing: view.annotation?.title!))")
}

fileprivate func setupLocationManager() {self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() == true {

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .restricted || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .denied || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {

            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }

        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = 1.0
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    } else {
        print("PLease turn on location services or GPS")
    }

}

fileprivate func setupMapView() {
    let mView = MKMapView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
    mView.showsUserLocation = true
    view.addSubview(mView)
    mView.showsScale = true
    mView.showsPointsOfInterest = true
    mView.showsTraffic = true
    mView.showsCompass = true
    mView.userTrackingMode = .follow
    self.mapView = mView
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks buggy:

`print("annotation title == \(String(describing: view.annotation?.title!))")`

If `annotation` is nil, you're force unwrapping it with `!` which would cause that crash.

Use instead:

`print("annotation title == \(String(describing: view.annotation?.title))")`

---

It's also not clear that you've called `setupMapView()` and actually set `mapView` before `viewDidLoad()` is called.  In `viewDidLoad()` add the line:

`if mapView == nil { setupMapView() }`

before using `mapView`.

Comment: This is fixed the error of unexpectedly  found nil but now my pin is not showing up on the map. Do you know why?

Comment: I'm afraid not.  Maybe your coordinates are wrong, maybe `mapView(_:viewFor:)` is returning `nil` before it returns a view.  It could be something else entirely... you'll have to do some debugging.